# Golang - Performance difference between literals and constants

Tags: performance, go, constants

I mostly use constants for documentation purposes e.g. a useful variable name or when I repeat certain sequences of strings over and over and don't want to change them manually. But I was wondering whether there's any performance difference. Am I right in my assumptions that there's no runtime difference between a literal and a constant, since constants are replaced at runtime?

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but I didn't find anything that tells me that this is wrong. The Go Tour doesn't provide any valuable information on and nor did the Constants blog post.

Comment: Check the go assembly?

Comment: I am not too big on assembly and I can't tell the performance implications of the resulting assembly, especially since it's an abstraction layer and byte-code instruction count probably doesn't indicate what performance it will yield.

Comment: My personal performance optimisations rule of thumb: if I cannot measure something (due to complexity or lack of experience), then I went too far and I don't really need it.

Comment: Yeah, premature optimisations aren't useful, I know that. I just wanted to know for the future. For example when you have to search a sorted list and you know it's faster to do it with binary search and you already have a binary search function, it's a no-brainer to use it, right?

Comment: I understand that _in the worst case_ it's a single instruction to read it from data segment. I never in my life needed to optimise go apps to that degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that says one way or another whether even this trivial program:

```
package main
func main() {}
```

might run fast as lightning when compiled on a Tuesday, but slow as molasses when compiled on a late Friday afternoon.  (Perhaps the Go compiler is anxious to head home for a beer and a weekend off and produced terrible code on Friday afternoon.<sup>1</sup>)

That said, if you're comparing, e.g.:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
const hello = "hello"
var playground = "playground"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", hello, playground)
}
```

we might note that in the `const` variant (`hello`), the compiler is *forced* to know at compile time that the string literal `"hello"` is a string literal, while in the `var` variant (`playground`), the compiler *could* be lazy and assume that the variable `playground` might be modified in some other function.  This in turn, combined with the ability of the compiler to know that `fmt.Println` is a *particular* function—the way GCC inserts special knowledge of the C `printf` function, for instance—*could* allow the compiler to more easily compile this to:

```
fmt.Printf("hello, %s\n", playground)
```

where only one runtime `reflect` happens, in case the variable `playground` has changed.  But the existing Go compilers use [SSA](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15411-f08/lectures/09-ssa.pdf) (see also https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/) and there are no writes to the variable, so we can expect simple (and usually simple = fast) runtime code here.

Playing with [the Godbolt compiler site](https://godbolt.org/), it seems that when using `const`, the current compiler actually has to insert one conversion to string.  The `var` version winds up with less runtime code.  I didn't test it with string literals inserted.  The `%s` directives are never expanded in line, but `fmt.Printf` really calls `fmt.Fprintf` directly, with `os.Stdout` as the first argument.

Overall, you're usually best off writing the *clearest* code you can.  Then, if it's too slow (for whatever definition you have of "too slow"), measure.  I'm guilty of overdoing my coding-time optimization myself, though. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>[Don't anthropomorphize computers.  They hate that!](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/8696204-don-t-anthropomorphize-computers-they-hate-it)

Comment: You mentioned that when using the const, it does a conversion to string at runtime. Might the reason for that be that you used an untyped string instead of a typed string, e.g. `const x string  = "x"``?

Comment: Possibly. Use the Godbolt page to try it out. (You'll have to look closely at the assembly output.)

Comment: Guess I'll have to learn go assembly then ^^ Thanks anyway, I assume there's no 100% correct answer, so i'll just mark yours as correct.